# How to fix 'Connection refused' error in FastAPI when calling a local app from another one?

Tags: python-requests, network-programming, fastapi

I have two FastAPI apps which is running on my localhost.
Let's say A and B apps.

A: `uvicorn A:api --reload --port 8081`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseMode


api = FastAPI()

class Data(BaseModel):
    name: str
    result: str

@api.post('/write')
def write(data: Data):
    # ... some logic
    return {'status': "OK"}
```

B: `uvicorn B:api --reload --port 8080`

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, BackgroundTasks
import requests


api = FastAPI()

def process(callback:str):
    req_body = {
        "name": "name",
        "result": "result"
    }
    response = requests.post(
        url=callback, 
        json=req_body 
    )
    # response = httpx.post(url=callback, 
    #                       json=req_body)
    
@api.post('/process')
def processing(
    background_tasks: BackgroundTasks,
    callback: str,
    ):
    background_tasks.add_task(process, callback)
    return {'status': "OK"}
```

The logic is following: I can call application B by specifying the callback URL that it will call when it completes the task. Callback URL is the endpoint of app A 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/write'.
And when I make a request from any client to application B, I get an error that app B cannot establish a connection with app A.

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8001): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /write
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f9e3dd60490>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I have tried using built-in fast api client and postman to call app B:
[image]
BTW, I can call app A separately and it works fine.

I really can't figure out what the problem is and I'm pretty stuck.

Comment: And you're not running these in docker containers or anything like that? Just two regular terminals, one in each?

Comment: @M.O. Yes that's right